# Can I say: "This teacher is going to cut us loose from the class"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm asking about the usage of the phrase "**cut someone loose**" that I saw which its meaning is "to free", but I'm not sure if it's appropriate in this context. Is it?

An example:

> "This teacher is going to **cut us loose** from the class"?

meaning the teacher is going to cancel the class today.

Comment: You haven't really explained the context. It sounds distinctly odd to say that a teacher is *cutting you loose* from a class. We usually say that a teacher is *excusing* you from class (for some reason).

Comment: Please use it in a sentence

Comment: Where I can fond example for uses of this phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to cut someone loose

means to "free someone who is being bound" (as in a rescue operation) and may even imply that the person being freed is then motivated to escape or run away

> The prisoners were ***cut loose*** from their chains.

In the sentence

> The children were ***cut loose*** from their class.
>   *the children where freed from the shackles of establishment imposed education and ran to the ice cream shop*

the action would be understandable, however, for classes, better phrasing might be

> The children were ***let go*** from their class.

since there probably wasn't a rescue operation which freed the children.